# C# DataGridView Binding from condition in SQL(Access) don't show data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I don't know what's happening. Why data don't show in datagridview when I use where condition in SQL.
It's don't have any error. It's only show Row header. But when I tried delete the condition out It's show data. What wrong with my code?

```
string model = txtmodel.text;

// Try to delete condition
//string sql = "SELECT id, model, comercial_model AS [Comercial model], ean AS [Package No], type AS Unit FROM models";

string sql = "SELECT id, model, comercial_model AS [Comercial model], ean AS [Package No], type AS Unit FROM models WHERE model Like '@model*'";

conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand dtcmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
dataadapter.SelectCommand = dtcmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//Add Parameters and set values.  
dtcmd.Parameters.Add("@model", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = model;

dataadapter.Fill(ds, "tbmodel");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "tbmodel";

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know what wrong with my code. It's must be

```
string sql = "SELECT id, model, comercial_model AS [Comercial model], ean AS [Package No], type AS Unit FROM models WHERE model Like @model";
```

and

```
dtcmd.Parameters.Add("@model", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = model+"%";
```

but I still don't understand why the code must be like this. Who can tell me?